# T4MVC is generating namespace for controllers incorrectly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, t4mvc

I've just plugged T4MVC (3.5.1) into my ASP.NET MVC3 project.

It seems to be generating the wrong namespace in the *.generated.cs files. For example:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;
using T4MVC;

namespace MyCompany.MyCompany.MyProject.Web.Controllers
{
    public partial class HomeController
    {
        //snip

        [GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public partial class T4MVC_HomeController : MyCompany.MyCompany.MyProject.Web.Controllers.HomeController
        {
            //snip
        }

        //snip
    }
}
```

In this generated file, the first `MyCompany` shows `MyCompany.MyCompany` in intellisense, so the generated namespace is trying to look for my controller at `MyCompany.MyCompany.MyCompany.MyProject.Web.Controllers.HomeController`, and of course `MyCompany.MyCompany` does not contain `MyCompany`!

How can I get T4MVC to generate the namespace correctly for my solution?

Comment: Since you opened https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/workitem/20, we can keep the discussion over there.

Comment: Thanks for the super speeds responses David!

Answer (score 1):

David Ebbo pointed me in the right direction, someone else had the same issue here:
https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/discussions/404550

I used the `global::` solution mentioned there, specifically, in `T4MVC.tt`, line 321, I changed:

```
public partial class <#=controller.DerivedClassName #> : <#=controller.FullClassName #>
```

to

```
public partial class <#=controller.DerivedClassName #> : global::<#=controller.FullClassName #>
```

---

Edit:
I also had to update line 1592 to account for parameters (my Models were having the same namespace issue). I did a quick and dirty change from this:

```
TT.Write(p.Type + " " + p.Name);
```

To this:

```
if (p.Type.StartsWith("FooBar"))
    TT.Write("global::" + p.Type + " " + p.Name);
else
    TT.Write(p.Type + " " + p.Name);
```